# Embedded references in jenssegers/laravel-mongodb to prevent data duplication

Tags: mongodb, laravel, eloquent, jenssegers-mongodb

I've collections: users, organisations, emails. A user can have 1..* emails. Even so an organisation can have 1..* emails.

Without linking tables (that's the NoSQL principe), these are my collections:

### User Collection:

```
[{'_id': ObjectId("54feabdae75a4f4168b7acd9"), 'name': 'Henri', 'emails': [{'_id': '54feabdae75a4f4168b7acda'}] }]
```

### Organisation Collection:

```
[{'_id': ObjectId("54feabdae75a4f4168be24a4"), 'name': 'MyOrg.org', 'emails': [{'_id': '54feabdae75a4f4168b7acda'}] }]
```

### Email Collection:

```
[{ "_id" : ObjectId("54feabdae75a4f4168b7acda"), "email" : "henriabc@gmail.com" }]
```

My relationships from "user" Model and "organisation" Model:

```
public function emails() {
    return $this->embedsMany('App\Email');
}
```

Call to eager load:

```
public fullUser($id) {
    return User::find($id)->with('emails')->get();
}
```

But how to (eager) load an user with his emails? Method above doesn't populate emails.

Comment: I have the same question. did you get your answer anyway?

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
public fullUser($id) {
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->emails();
    return $user();
}
```